# I want to approve the comments made. Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an Approved column in a database which is false by default and might become true on "Approve" button click.

That's what this button look like at the moment:

```erb
<%= link_to('Approve It', @comment_path, method: :update) %>
```

But it raises an exception:

> No route matches [POST] "/books/4/comments/6

```ruby
# app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
def update
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  @comment.approve = true

  redirect_to '/dashboard'
end
```

```ruby
# config/routes.rb
resources :books do
  resources :comments
end
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Don't you want that method to be `:patch` (or `:put`) and not `:update`?

Comment: @jvillian , How can i do that ? Do I need to change the comments_controller.rb file?

Comment: You would change `:update` to `:patch` or `:put` in your `show.html.erb`.

Comment: @jvillian I've tried both but still get the same error.

Comment: @jvillian i tried many time and finally it's work. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Post / Update actions require forms

You're using a `link_to`. This is good for GET requests, but is no good for POST/PATCH/UPDATE requests. For that you'll have to use a form in HTML. Luckily Rails offers some short cut. You can use something like `button_to`:

```
<%= button_to "Approve", { controller: "comments", action: "update" }, remote: false, form: { "id" => @comment.id, "approved" => true } %>
```

This creates a form for you. Which will come with CSRF protection automatically. You can style the button however you like.

or you could use a link to:

```
 <%= link_to comment_approved_path(@comment), method: :put %>
```

but then you would need to create a separate "approved" action in your controller, and a separate route to reach it.

(The above code has not been tested).

Answer (score 2):

`link_to` has to point to an existing route/action, with a proper method name. There is no `:update` HTTP method.

FYI: *Approve* action doesn't seem like it belongs to the `#update` method/action. You might want to extract it to a separate route like so:

```ruby
resources :books do
  resources :comments do
    post :approve, on: :member
  end
end
```

this is more idiomatic/common approach in Ruby because `#update` is usually preserved for more general object updates.

For this you will need to change `:method` argument value to `:post` and update your route/@comment_path.

[Rails-ujs event handlers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#rails-ujs-event-handlers) - this link might be useful for understanding how it works behind the scenes.

[Controller Namespaces and Routing](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

Comment: doesn't `link_to` support pointing to controller actions (as well as paths) - see here: https://apidock.com/rails/v2.1.0/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to . Agreed - OP might want to think about a separate action, or even a separate controller and action if OP wants to be dogmatic about restful interfaces.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon you were right. I've slightly adjusted my comment to be less confusing. Thanks for noticing

Answer (score 1):

```
#html
<%= link_to "Approve It", book_comment_path(@comment), method: 'put' %>

# app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
def update
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  @comment.approve = true
  @comment.save 

  redirect_to '/dashboard'
end
```